# locating and removing malware in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps

I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 for my Rails app hosted on a VPS. I have followed the instructions for using IP tables to create a firewall, and also added fail2ban. However, within 24 hours of launch the site to the IP address (i.e. no domain) and giving it to about 5 test users, the site's already been infected by some php scripts. I found this in the logs..

```
(No route matches [GET] "/admm/scripts/setup.php"): 
Started GET "//mysqlmanager/scripts/setup.php"
```

Is there a recommended way to locate and remove the malware in a Rails app? My instinct is to destroy the server and restart from scratch but that's obviously not ideal as I assume it'll just happen again...

I'm afraid to rsync the app to my local machine as it might bring crap onto my local computer. I'm looking through individual files in the Rails app with nano but I can't see any of the actual malware. Should I be looking in a server directory rather than the Rails app itself?

Comment: How's the site running since the time of this post? Any malware issues? Curious about your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not malware.

What you are seeing is an exploit scanner looking for security holes. It is a GET request coming from a remote machine and your Rails app is responding correctly with HTTP 404 for the URL.

Those requests will keep coming, there is nothing you can do about it.